# Problem to create background in language other than English in the settings

Tags: python

This is a script part that creates a background, i i run that in Blender with language default (English) run ok , but if i change for example in Spanish 
line 3 give error KeyError: `'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Background" not found'` , because "Background" is translate to "Fondo".
Now i have not intention to translate all name for all languages, exist simple way to change that script to make work in another languages?

```
1- new_world = bpy.data.worlds.new('My background')
2- new_world.use_nodes = True
3- node = new_world.node_tree.nodes['Background']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Default nodes are in same order**

Since you are looking at the default nodes created when setting a world to use nodes, then the zeroth item is the output node, and the first the background node.

Simply reference them on creation, rather than using a key.

```
>>> nw = bpy.data.worlds.new("xxxx")
>>> nw.use_nodes = True
>>> nw.node_tree.nodes[:]
[bpy.data...nodes["World Output"], bpy.data...nodes["Background"]]

>>> output, bg = nw.node_tree.nodes
>>> output
bpy.data...nodes["World Output"]

>>> bg
bpy.data...nodes["Background"]
```

**To translate**

To find what blender translates from the english to the currently set locale,

[image]

```
>>> bpy.app.translations.locale
'es'

>>> nw.node_tree.nodes[:]
[bpy.data...nodes["Entorno"], bpy.data...nodes["Fondo"]]

>>> bpy.app.translations.pgettext("World Output")
'Entorno'

>>> bpy.app.translations.pgettext("Background")
'Fondo'
```

Comment: I think this person **doesn't** want to translate it one by one every time.

Comment: I think you need to read the answer.

Comment: Hi @batFINGER i think found the solution node = new_world.node_tree.nodes.get('Background') right?

Comment: Huh?  simply `node = bg`  using that is same as question code only you get `node is None` instead of a key error. ie if you run `output, bg = new_world.node_tree.nodes` it doesn't matter what language you are in.  The name set will be `bg.name` .  I can't be much clearer than this.

Comment: I tried this because the blender console from "Background" even when you change language in auto-complete(Shift-Space) , seems to work now, remember to be careful about the ['Background'] method because I see that there are many tutorials with this error

Comment: Have try that method with get? i check now in all languages... it seems to work

Comment: AFACT `node = new_world.node_tree.nodes.get('Background')` does not work for all languages.  In spanish it gives me `None` because it is named "Fondo"  This is going around in circles. If you think that is the answer post it.  Make sure you are creating the new world in each new language, and not keeping a reference to one created in english.

Comment: Ok @batFINGER , I'd like to head just because it looks for me works, I don't understand why

Comment: @batFINGER, ok i understand why, in my script the world is created ex-novo with an operator that operator clear old World , then create new. he never refers to old worlds. That is my solution

Comment: ... whereas my solution is to the question.

Comment: bat , i have try that method (get)  in blender 2.79 , 2.8 with language different, i not understand but im not with that error

Comment: `ob = bpy.data.objects.get("I do not exist")` throws no error.   It sets `ob` to `None`. instead of throwing a key error.  What would be a key-error is now the case if `ob is None`. If we continue without testing then something like  `ob.location` throws an error `Nonetype has no attribute "location"`  In this case the lack of error still has `node`  referencing nothing if there is no node named "Background".

Comment: Right , now i understand , ty